# Extend existing object with conditional properties

Tags: typescript

I wonder how to deal with this example. There is declared object and I want to conditionally add properties to object. Is there any way to do it?

```js
  let condition = true;
  
  const config = {
    ...otherProps,
    type: "date",
    variant: "outlined",
    fullWidth: true,
    InputLabelProps: {
      shrink: true,
    },
  };
  
 if (condition) {
    config.error = true;
    config.helperText = 'error';
  }
```

I've errors:

```
Property 'error' does not exist on type

Property 'helperText' does not exist on type
```

Comment: How's it supposed to know those _are_ valid props? It's just getting an implicit type from the object literal.

Comment: Should it be typed explicit? `config` was dynamic typed that's I didn't use interface before

Comment: Well if you're not happy with the inferred type, being explicit seems like a good idea no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't assign a type with the initial assignment, then Typescript infers a type from the value at that point. Typescript does *not* look ahead and make other assignments part of that that type. This means that the type of `config` is locked in after it gets assigned to a value, and then you try to write unknown properties that aren't part of that type and get an error.

---

The quick fix is to make the conditional part of the initial assignment.

```
let condition = true;
  
const config = {
    type: "date",
    variant: "outlined",
    fullWidth: true,
    InputLabelProps: {
      shrink: true,
    },
    ...(condition ? { error: true, helperText: 'error' } : {})
}

config.error // (property) error?: boolean | undefined
```

Now typescript can properly infer that `error` and `helperText` exist and are optional.

[See Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=4.9.0-dev.20221017#code/DYUwLgBAxg9gdgEwJZifCBeCYBOBXEAbgFgAoCCM2OAZ0moDMkBzTCAbzIorAE8AHEAC4IAIgQBDMCFEAaLtwBuEnEglwwI0TDxhgSOCARyFFBnmDAA6kgRgAFiNwF55bgEk4-XQBkJAIxBgAAUcGH4aEU43bggae1U4AGsnfBBXWIBfDO4AOnyACmpkVHQAfg4IEBwwnFSXCHsgwRwAFRAAD00IAHJq2p6ITIgozIBKMkyyKngmZlz+mBwIAHoViAL+MJa+MaqapbKRfxgYUHUIAB8IPEQQJkMEMiA)

---

But a better solution is to make a proper type for this object. It seems like more work up front, but robust types will save you a lot of time and headache in the long run.

```
interface Config {
    type: 'date' | 'text' | 'whatever'
    variant?: 'outlined' | 'filled' | 'default'
    fullWidth?: boolean
    InputLabelProps: { shrink: boolean },
    error?: boolean
    helperText?: string
} // or something

let condition = true;

const config: Config = {
    type: "date",
    variant: "outlined",
    fullWidth: true,
    InputLabelProps: {
      shrink: true,
    },
}

if (condition) {
    config.error = true;
    config.helperText = 'error';
}
```

[See playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&ts=4.9.0-dev.20221017#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMIHsQ2Ac2QbwFgAoZM5MATwAcIAuZAcgBM5JHkAfJyADzA7dGAdwAWbCADdojEuWSS4UYHHAB+Bo3QBXMABtQEZoKbY9eoyZYR42vQLnkYdvQHVgzMKI3IARunQLVUcyAEkQal0AGThfCD0ABSh0agBnBnxkVNFlEABrBn9AiFVkAF8AGhDkaGSoHyKgkGrReNooABUIfh9UsFycEjLkAHoR5HQoLPQAWwgvUEHiEgswZARMZmAwYExkAF4KKG0IAG4SEg2QPvXMbBwGDCxcA4JqqloGACJWSC+q0jkRTKVRgb46fSGZj-arOczuTyiBj9E4A+ThSJgGJxRLJNIZapkbK5ApHVHVSpDC7EYAwZAACiuWx2mAAlG9AWQrvcAHS1SavFFnarc3A81p6dpdfivRj8qCMc7EMokIA)

Comment: You explained me everything. I'm really appreciate, thank you!!!